# Вопрос с компонентом в библиотеке (может быть)

Tags: delphi, dll, библиотеки

Есть библиотека с несколькими формами.
На одной из форм (*FAuthentication*), располагается «*IBDatabase2*» (это новый компонент, т.е. к нему ничего не подключено и т.п. настроены только «*user name*» «*password*» и «*character set*»)
После вызова одной из функций библиотеки

```
function BACKUP_DB(AFBackupCreate: boolean;
                   var APathDB: string): string; export; stdcall; far;
var
  LNameDB: string;
begin
  if AFBackupCreate then
  begin
    FAuthentication := TFAuthentication.Create(nil);
  FAuthentication.IBDatabase2.DatabaseName := APathDB;
  FAuthentication.IBDatabase2.Connected := true;  <-- ошибка

  end;

if AFBackupCreate then
  begin
    FreeAndNil(FAuthentication);
  end;
```

и закрытия приложения, которое вызвало dll ошибка в памяти

> exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at
>   0x04eda150: read of address 0x0563e844

'.

Она происходит из-за строки 
«`FAuthentication.IBDatabase2.Connected := true`»

Я теряюсь в догадках, где может быть ошибка…
P.S.
- Хотя при вызове других функций этой же библиотеки отрабатывают нормально
- - добавил в dll новую форму и на нее кинул IBDatabase2 - эффект тот же

Comment: `ShareMem` используется?

Comment: @Igor, конечно, какже без него..., самым первым в *.dpr,

Comment: интересно, то что, если я в самом компоненте «IBDataBase» при проектировании укажу «DataBaseName» и «Connected = true», то ошибка перестает вылетать. Т.е. ошибка будет, только если во время работы программы, я буду менять значения этих 2-х параметров

Comment: у меня в приложении (вызывающем dll) есть свой database, так вот если я передаю в dll в качестве параметра значение "DatabaseName", при закрытии приложения - ошибка, А если передаю обычную переменную - строка с путем к БД - все ОК, Оба значения и "DatabaseName" и переменная РАВНЫ

Comment: ShareMem используется в обоих проектах?

Comment: нет, только в dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShareMem` используется в обоих проектах?

> нет, только в dll

Ну вот и всё - это ответ.

Вы передаете через границу ехе/dll строку - тип данных, управление памятью и жизненным циклом которого осуществляется компилятором в спрятанном от нашего кода виде. Это страшно удобно, но об этом надо знать - как раз для таких случаев.

Comment: да после добавления "sharemem" в *.dpr, программы вызывающей dll, программы, ошибка ушла. 
**Спасибо**.